# how to make a loop to get specific items from a list? - python

Tags: python

about the program:

> in this program I need to get user's input for making a 'quiz' first
> asks for the no. of questions and then asks the question text and 4
> 'answers' , and ask for the correct answer from those 4 answers.
> repeats for the no. of questions.
>
> like a 'quiz maker'

> list_of_questions stores the text for questions
>
> list_of_keys stores the inputed 'answers' (in order) for all questions
> Example:

```
list_of_keys = [Q1_Answer1, Q1_Answer2, Q1_Answer3, Q1_Answer4, Q2_Answer1, Q2_Answer2, Q2_Answer3, Q2_Answer4, Q3_Answer1 etc...]
```

In start_quiz() I need to first print the 1st question  text and the 4 answers and then 2nd question text and the 4 answers etc...

**using a loop to get the specific items from the list**

BUT the loop I have made below : just prints the same first 4 answers over again.

I can't find a solution to get the items correctly from the list.

I tried this but it didn't work: (out of range error)

```
var1 = 0
for I in main_list:
    answer_amount = 4
    if answer_amount > 0:
        var1 += 1
        print(list_of_keys[var1])
```

the entire code:

```
from questionclass import Question_template

main_list = []

list_of_questions = []
list_of_answers = []
list_of_keys = []


print("\n Quiz maker \n")


def make_quiz():
    X = 0
    Z = 0
    Y = 0
    amount_of_answers = 4
    question_amount = int(input(" Enter number of questions for     your quiz: "))
    while question_amount > 0:
        question_amount -= 1
        X += 1
        list_of_questions.append(str(input(" Text for question no." + str(X) + ": ")))
        while amount_of_answers > 0:
            amount_of_answers -= 1
            Y += 1
            list_of_keys.append((str(Y) + ".") + str(input("  Answer no." + str(Y) + ": ")))
        amount_of_answers = 4
        list_of_answers.append(int(input("\nwhich answer is the correct answer?\n")))
        Y = 0
    for question in list_of_questions:
        main_list.append(Question_template(question, list_of_keys[Z], list_of_answers[Z]))
        Z += 1
    start_quiz()

def start_quiz():
    key = int(input("\n enter 0 to start quiz: "))
    score = 0
    If key == 0:
        for question in main_list: 
            print(question.promt) # printing the question text
            amount_of_answers = 4


            for i in list_of_keys:     ####THIS LOOP HERE#### 
                if amount_of_answers > 0:
                    print(i)
                    amount_of_answers -= 1


            answer = int(input(""))
            if answer == list_of_answers[0]:
                score += 1

makequiz()
```

question class:

```
class Question_template:
    def __init__(self, promt, answers, correct):
        self.promt = promt
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correct
```

Comment: my advice is to break down your code in simpler forms or seperate them. for starters you have a syntax error where you used 'IF' instead of if

Comment: in which line is the syntax error ??

Comment: If key == 0: 3rd line in start_quiz

Comment: when I copy pasted the code I must have accidentally capitalised it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the every time same answers due to fact that you iterate every time from starting point of the list_of_keys. For question 1 you iterate between 0 to 4 and for question 2 you iterate between 0 4 again. However, your information is between 4 and 8 for question 2. Therefore, you should add a key counter that stores which question you are looking for. Therefore, I have added keyCounter, and increased it to 4 for every question. In addition to this you should also start from that point in the list_of_keys like list_of_keys[keyCounter:].

```
def start_quiz():
    key = int(input("\n enter 0 to start quiz: "))
    score = 0
    keyCounter = 0
    if key == 0:
        for question in main_list:
            print(question.promt) # printing the question text
            amount_of_answers = 4

            for i in list_of_keys[keyCounter:]:     ####THIS LOOP HERE####
                if amount_of_answers > 0:
                    print(i)
                    amount_of_answers -= 1
            keyCounter = keyCounter + 4
```